# Any alternative to nautilus-image-converter for dolphin?

Tags: filemanager, image-processing, dolphin

I do most of my image conversion using **converseen**. But it would be really easy if there was an extension for dolphin so that I could convert image size just on right click. Is there such an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a third-party plugin available. Download it from here by switching to **File** Tab https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1126887/ or from [this direct link](http://bouveyron.free.fr/kim/release/kim4-0.9.5.tar.gz)

Now extract it and go to its directory. From terminal use these commands:

```
sudo cp src/kim_*.desktop /usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
sudo cp src/bin/kim_* /usr/bin/
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/bin/kim_*
sudo chmod a+r /usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/kim_*.desktop
sudo mkdir /usr/share/kim
sudo cp COPYING /usr/share/kim/kim_about.txt
sudo mkdir /usr/share/kim/slideshow/
sudo cp src/slideshow/* /usr/share/kim/slideshow/
sudo mkdir /usr/share/kim/gallery
sudo cp src/gallery/* /usr/share/kim/gallery
```

Now restart dolphin. It'll be in the **Actions** menu.

Comment: wow, this is better than nautilus-image-converter. Thanx. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [imgp](https://github.com/jarun/imgp). It's a terminal utility with many more features.